# print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[int(input())//10]) how does this python code work?

Tags: python, string

How does this code work??

```
print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[int(input())//10])
```

The meaning of the code above seems to be

```
s = int(input())//10
if s==10 or 9: print('A')
elif s==8: print('B')
elif s==7: print('C')
elif s==6: print('D')
else: print('F')
```

But what I can see is just string and list; I think somehow they correspond one to the other, but how..? Just writing a list next to a string?

Comment: `just writing list next to string?` It's not a list. It's the indexing operator. Similar to if you write `a[0]`

Comment: Try `'FFFFFFDCBAA'[8]`. A string behaves like a list, and `[]` is accessing an item by index. See the examples in: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#text

Comment: If it was e.g. `str = 'FFFFFFDCBAA'; i = 0; print(str[i])` what would you expect?

Comment: There's no list in your code. The `[]` is the indexing operator. It simply indexes into the string. Try this: `'abcdef'[3]` and you'll see how it works.

Comment: um I thought some function which domain = 1,2,3,..,10, codomain = A, B, C, .., F,F,F. but now understand thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Right.  It's the same as `s = 'abcdef'` / `print(s[3])`.

Comment: Also please remove list from your tags, this question has nothing to do with lists.

Answer (score 1):

For a more detailed explanation, you may read on. Suppose you have `s = 'FFFFFFDCBAA'` To get the character with index 10 in string s, you can `print(s[10])` and you'll get 'A'. In this example, s is assigned the string 'FFFFFFDCBAA'. You can also use the literal without assigning to s i.e. printing `'FFFFFFDCBAA'[10]` will still output 'A' because 'A' is the character with index 10 in the literal. With this basics, we can go on to answer your specific question.

`print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[int(input())//10])` simply tells the interpreter to accept an integer from the user, perform floor division by 10 and return the integer part of the result. This now becomes the index of the string literal `'FFFFFFDCBAA'` hence it's enclosed in `[]`.

For example, if a user enters 56, `56//10 = 5`. This is what the interpreter will execute `print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[5])` which means to print the character with index 5 in your literal which is 'F'.

Comment: print(s[10]) will print the 11th character in the string (providing there are at least 11 characters in the string)

Comment: @Codist We all know that index starts at 0. So perhaps i should have said character with index 10? Of course a higher index without any matching character would result in 'IndexError: string index out of range'. Not sure you wanted me to include all these details in my answer. THANKS for the downvote

Comment: I have removed the downvote following your corrections

Comment: Thanks for spotting that out. I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down. You have:

```
print('FFFFFFDCBAA'[int(input())//10])
```

This is unnecessarily obfuscated. If we break it down into its functionality (step by step) then it should become clearer.

```
s = 'FFFFFFDCBAA' # assign to a discrete variable
v = input() # get input from stdin
i = int(v) # this will raise a ValueError exception if the input string cannot be converted to int
N = i // 10 # perform floor (integer) division on the converted input value
slen = len(s) # get length of string
assert N >= -slen and N < slen # validate the index w.r.t length of string
print(s[N]) # print the Nth character from the string
```

Comment: I like this breakdown